# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 1266: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, scikit-learn

I am trying to train some text data using scikit. The same code is being used on other PC without any error but on my system it gives error:

```
File "/root/Desktop/karim/svn/questo-anso/v5/trials/classify/domain_detection_final/test_classifier_temp.py", line 130, in trainClassifier
    X_train = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(self.data_train.data)
  File "/root/Desktop/karim/software/scikit-learn-0.15.1/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1270, in fit_transform
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "/root/Desktop/karim/software/scikit-learn-0.15.1/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 808, in fit_transform
    vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary)
  File "/root/Desktop/karim/software/scikit-learn-0.15.1/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 741, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/root/Desktop/karim/software/scikit-learn-0.15.1/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 233, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "/root/Desktop/karim/software/scikit-learn-0.15.1/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 111, in decode
    doc = doc.decode(self.encoding, self.decode_error)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 1266: invalid start byte
```

I already checked similar threads but no helps.

UPDATE:

```
self.data_train = self.fetch_data(cache, subset='train')
if not os.path.exists(self.root_dir+"/autocreated/vectorizer.txt"):
                self.vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,
                                                 stop_words='english')
                start_time = time()
                print("Transforming the dataset")
                X_train = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(self.data_train.data)  // Error is here
                joblib.dump(self.vectorizer, self.root_dir+"/autocreated/vectorizer.txt")
```

Comment: 0xba is indeed an invalid start byte, what's the problem?

Comment: Encode text i.e `text.encode('utf8')` and review the text, you might get clue

Comment: @n.m.: even I dont know, the coding is fine, but dont know why it is showing encoding error

Comment: @MaNKuR: thanks, `text` is any variable ?

Comment: It may not be problem of code, but that of input text. Is the text 'utf-8'?  Did the same code and same text work fine in past? (You not mentioned about text.)

Comment: "the coding is fine". Your word against decoder's. How about looking at some actual evidence?

Comment: @user123, Yes `text` is a variable.

Comment: @Fumu7: I guess that might be the issue, but as the text content can be any, how can I deal with situation?

Comment: @n.m.: sorry, but I don't know from where it is reading `0xba`

Comment: @MaNKuR: I updated the code, I used `self.data_train.data.encode('utf8')` I got `AttributeError` i.e. `'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
` similar with `self.data_train.encode`

Comment: @n.m.: so If I dont understand something then I should giveu, right? you can leave this thread, I will handle

Comment: Well you said "I don't know" while having all the source code and all the source data. Who am I to suggest you to actually look at them and find out?

Comment: @n.m.: I am reading data from http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/20newsgroups/20newsgroups.html, it has so many files. And checked few of them, which show simplex text content only.

Comment: @user123 Ohk, I missed to tell that `text` variable should be of `string` type. `encode` method can be applied to `string/unicode` type only. For list and other object `encode` should be applied to its element that too should be of `string/unicode` type.

Comment: There is `doc = doc.decode(...)` line, why not insert some statements to print debug information around it? Or run the program in a debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your file is actually encoded in [ISO-8869-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1#ISO-8859-1), not UTF-8. You need to properly decode it before you can encode it again.

0xBA is the [numero sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign#Usages) (`º`) in ISO-8869-1.

Comment: thanks dude. Did you mean decoding the data that I am using for training purpose? I am using 20news group data http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/20newsgroups/20newsgroups.html. I also tried with copying text from wikipedia but even it was giving the same error.

Comment: and I also checked character encoding for the text which is `UTF-8`

Comment: ...and how did you check it?

Comment: in text editor, when we do `save as` it displays  current encoding . Even I tried to convert like `self.data_train.data = unicode(self.data_train.data, "utf-8")` but in that case `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found`

Comment: The editor shows you the editor's own internal setting, not the actual file encoding, which it cannot know.

Comment: oh okay thanks, I did not know it. The data which I am going to use is inside `self.data_train.data`, I tried to encode it. But it is saying var is list. Is there any way to convert list content to string and after encoding doing reverse process?

Comment: Hey thanks guys, it got solved using `decode_error='ignore'`. thanks for your efforts. I added answer which may help other

Answer (score 3):

There was issue in dealing with the training data. One thing that solved my issue is `ignoring error` using `decode_error='ignore'`, there might be some other solutions.

```
self.vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,stop_words='english',decode_error='ignore')
```

Comment: That's an awful solution. You are now just hiding the fact that you failed to create correct input files.